# PHP Laravel - Writing a 2 step CSV file Import process including mapping confirmation

Tags: php, csv

I'm currently building an application which allows a user to import a CSV file to a database. What I'm confused about is the best way to handle the 2nd import mapping process as I'm finding that the file information is lost.

Form first step asks user for a file:

[image]

The server handles the post, processes the csv and redirects back to the page with the import mapping and example data:

[image]

When the form posts again - how will the server know which file to look for? I was thinking of pushing the saved filepath back and including it as a hidden input, but I realise this is risky as it could be changed by the user. Maybe an encrypted string of some sort?

Any advice would be amazing, or if you can think of a better way of achieving this!

Also - Is there a nice way to only allow users to only select one option from the select dropdowns once?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an “upload” model, that stores the file path in the database. When a user uploads a CSV, you create a model instance and redirect to the form that has the option to map fields. When they set their fields, you process the CSV and delete the record. You can also have a scheduled task that cleans up unprocessed CSV files after a period of time, i.e. 24 hours.

Comment: I guess you would need to pass a value back to the form to identify the model row, maybe a uuid or something similar?

Comment: Yeah. But if you use an identifier like that, it means you don’t have to pass the file name as a parameter. In fact, the user may never see it!

Comment: If you have found a solution about this problem please can you help me on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359321/undefined-index-field-name-on-uploading-and-maching-data-on-db?noredirect=1#comment132979223_75359321 i really it