# Larval Undefined index: field_name on mapping fiele

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to edit code I found on a GitHub repository of Laravel Daily https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-8-Import-CSV.This is a system that matches the fields of the DB table and a .csv document before loading the data into the database. I'm trying to add some more fields to the table, but I'm getting an error `Undefined index: phone_number` because I don't have `phone_number` in the CSV document.

import_fields.blade

```
<tr>
  @foreach ($csv_data[0] as $key => $value)
   <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900">
    <select name="fields[{{ $key }}]">
    @foreach ($db_field as $field)
    <option value="{{ (\Request::has('header')) ? $field : $loop->index }}"
        @if ($key === $field) selected @endif>{{ $field }}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
  </td>
 @endforeach
</tr>
```

```
public function parseImport(CsvImportRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->has('header')) {
        $headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray($request->file('csv_file'));
        $data = Excel::toArray(new ContactsImport, $request->file('csv_file'))[0];
    } else {
        $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($request->file('csv_file')->getRealPath()));
    }

    if (count($data) > 0) {
        $csv_data = array_slice($data, 0, 2);

        $csv_data_file = CsvData::create([
            'csv_filename' => $request->file('csv_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
            'csv_header' => $request->has('header'),
            'csv_data' => json_encode($data)
        ]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    // I have added this function here to get fields from my table
    $contact = new Contact;
    $table = $contact->getTable();
    $db_field = \Schema::getColumnListing($table);

    return view('import_fields', [
        'headings' => $headings ?? null,
        'csv_data' => $csv_data,
        'csv_data_file' => $csv_data_file,
        'db_field' => $db_field
    ]);
}

public function processImport(Request $request)
{
    $data = CsvData::find($request->csv_data_file_id);
    $csv_data = json_decode($data->csv_data, true);
    foreach ($csv_data as $row) {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $table = $contact->getTable();
        $db_field = \Schema::getColumnListing($table);
        foreach ($db_field as $index => $field) {
            if ($data->csv_header) {
                if (array_key_exists($field, $request->fields)) {
                    $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$field]];
                }
            } else {
                if (array_key_exists($index, $request->fields)) {
                    $contact->$field = $row[$request->fields[$index]];
                }
            }
        }
        $contact->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('success', 'Import finished.');
}
```

My migration file is here

```
Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('phone_number');
});
```

Also, this is the structure of CSV I have

```
id  first_name  last_name   email   phone
```

When i do dd request here i get this result

```
  public function processImport(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->fields);

//RESULT
array:5 [▼
  "id" => "id"
  "first_name" => "first_name"
  "last_name" => "last_name"
  "email" => "email"
  "phone" => "phone_number"
]
```

I get this error when I try to match `phone` from CSV with `phone_number`from db

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'phone_number' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `contacts` (`email`, `first_name`, `id`, `last_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asorbie0@paginegialle.it, Ariela, 1, Sorbie, 2023-02-06 09:15:20, 2023-02-06 09:15:20))

[UPDATES]

if i add `phone` field on db table like this

```
Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('middle_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_number')->nullable();
```

and but trying to match value off `phone` to `phone_number` when uploading data from excel file , now i am getting this error.

```
Undefined index: phone_number
```

Comment: If there is no phone number in your csv, either remove it from the migration or also set that field to nullable, just like the middle name.

Comment: You DO have a phone number column in both the database and the CSV. The problem would appear to be that one is called `phone` and the orther is called `phone_number`. So once you have read `$headings = (new HeadingRowImport)->toArray($request->file('csv_file'));` change occurance `phone` to `phone_number`

Comment: @RiggsFolly But I don't want to have both fields in csv and db the same. I want that even though the field in the csv is `phone`, I can replace it with a different field in the database, which in this case could be `phone_number`, but in other cases it could be another field, for example `ph_number `or `number_phone`. Or in case I have some dummy data in csv and I want to insert it into a field in db, for example in csv it is` dummy` while in db it is `dummy_data`

Comment: @MatthewBradley I dont want to remove the field from db but need to insert there `phone` datas from csv . I think there is a way to make this happend, just does not know how

Comment: Then you are going to have to make some MAJOR changes to the code. And a magic wand wouuld also be a useful addition

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you help me with this changers, it is my first time i do this and have no idea how to make it happend. Iam trying to debug but cant find a worth solution . also i am adding something on y questions

Comment: My suggestion was not to make field names the same in both the CSV and the DB. I suggested that you will have to know what the difference is, and then in the code amend the name of the phone field in the `$headings` variable to match the database. Because that is what would be what was required to make this other persons code, work for you

Comment: `$headings` variable return me the heading row of csv fiele `array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▶
    0 => array:5 [▶
      0 => "id"
      1 => "first_name"
      2 => "last_name"
      3 => "email"
      4 => "phone"
    ]
  ]
]` I think the  difference here is `phone` csv => `phone_number` db.   but how can i do this `$headings variable to match the database`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you do any example?\

Comment: Can you show a simple `var_export($headings)`

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'id', 1 => 'first_name', 2 => 'last_name', 3 => 'email', 4 => 'phone', ), ), )  result of `var_export($headings)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly You deletet your answer, does it mean it was wrong way of doing this?

Comment: No, just didnt have time to work out why you get an error that shoudl not happen

Comment: I am trying to understand that too, have 2 days working on this already

Comment: Any solution about this problem?